# Using Unix to send email to outlook users

Tags: linux, email, unix

I would like to ask you tiny question how to handle this small situation as described below:

I actually need to create script where I should check the user first and send email (to outlook email) with a log file.  the issue here is that email id is not matching with UNIX id which means I can't simply do mail -s 'test' $USER@abc.com

Any tips will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to use BASH? can you use python or PHP instead?

Comment: `touch $USER:logs.`date +"%m-%d-%y"`.log
if [ $USER -eq sha ]; then
emailsha=shah@abc.com
echo 'Error Found ' | mail -s 'ERROR FOUND' $emailsha<$USER:logs.`date +"%m-%d-%y"`.log
elif [ $USER -eq tan ]
then
emailtan=tan@abc.com
echo 'Error Found ' | mail -s 'ERROR FOUND' $emailtan<$USER:logs.`date +"%m-%d-%y"`.log
elif [ $USER -eq shah23 ]
then
emailshah=shah23@abc.com
echo 'Error Found ' | mail -s 'ERROR FOUND' $emailshah<$USER:logs.`date +"%m-%d-%y"`.log
else
 echo "Opps! $USER is not recognized user"
fi`

Comment: I mocked up multilevel ifelse statement this how I am trying to solve the issue but it seems it's not reading other than the first pass

Comment: Please advise if there is any better way . appreciated for your help with this.

Comment: I was able to do it with this - it works now. thanks